# Cannot boot from HDD after installation 14.04

Tags: boot, grub2

I'm new to Ubuntu and installed to my Lenovo B570 laptop.

Followed installer and successfully completed to "restart" when restart happens it say to remove installation DVD and hit enter.

After that, it did not boot,even the boot order is hdd on top.

If I choose DVD (had to put in again), then it boots and have Ubuntu working.
I find some weird thing in here because it does not ask me to login (I set it up during the install process) and the time zone is completely different from what i input during the install process. Look like I have not done the job correctly.

Comment: If you boot from the DVD, of course it won't login and will have the wrong time zone - it's a live session, not your install :)

Comment: but it won't boot from hard disk

Comment: what should i try? any recommendation?

Comment: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15503361

Comment: I've messed up with gparted and the above is the result of boot-repair. please help me how to address this problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the date and time from the boot loader. Maybe that should help with the problem. And about booting from HDd check if you have made a separate partition for Ubuntu Operating System.

Comment: I tried changing partition but messed it up. I have uploaded boot-repair results http://paste.ubuntu.com/15503361 , can you guide me how I tackle from here?